# Can I change the default item count site-wide for all current and future lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, view

In SharePoint Online, the default item count per page of a list is 30 items per page. While this can be modified at will, it can only be done *per list*, as far as I am aware.

I have a scenario where a user uploads many new pages/lists and he finds it rather cumbersome to have to go into each list and edit the view to change this value for each list.

Is there any way to modify the 'definition', per se, of the AllItems default list view on a *site-wide* basis so that all current (and ideally future) lists have their default item count changed?

I'm looking for a way this can be done from within the web UI or at worst in SharePoint Designer, rather than programmatically via PowerShell, ideally.